# Generating function of $a_{n} = n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I want to find the closed form of this  $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} {nx^{n}}$
Is the following correct?

$(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n)^{'}= (1)^{'}+(x)^{'}+(x^2)^{'}+(x^3)^{'}+...=$
$0 + 1 +2x + 3x^2 + ...=$
$=(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n-1}})=(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {(k-1)x^{k}})= (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {kx^{k}}) - (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {x^{k}})$   $,(1)$

But this $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {x^{k}} = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n)^{'} = (\frac{1}{1-x})^{'}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

So from $(1)$ we have $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} {x^{n}})^{'}=(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {kx^{k}}) - (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {x^{k}})\Rightarrow\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} {nx^{n}})-\frac{1}{1-x}$

According to my notes it should be equal $\frac{x}{(1-x)^{2}}$ thoough, but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Yes this is correct. Can you justify the termwise differentiation? Thanks.

Comment: It's correct but to perfect your solution you should also invoke some results on radius of convergence to justify why you can take termwise differentiation.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Do we have to justify termwise differentiation if it's a formal power series? Is this a formal power series? I was never good at this, haha

Comment: @Ilham Oh sorry, I did not see it was "formal generating" function, if this is the case, there is no problem :)

Comment: My notes state its equal to $x/(1-x)^2$ tho , are both solutions correct?

Comment: @Complex1238877 Why is $=(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n-1}})=(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {(k-1)x^{k}})$? Shouldn't it be $(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n-1}})=(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {(k+1)x^{k}})$?

Comment: Didn't notice that, you are right thats my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct except that
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n-1}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} {(k+1)x^k}
$$ and we are led to the correct result
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.
$$ or equivalently, multiplying by $x$:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n}}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$